# Как проверить что возвращает функция?

Tags: c++, opengl

Изучаю библиотеку DevIL, но плохо знаю с++...
там есть функция которая открывает изображение...
ilLoadImage(L"1.jpg");
В инструкции написано что если все хорошо, она что то должна возвращать.
Если что то не так возвращает false
Так выглядит мой код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как посмотреть что возвращает функция?
Вообще понять работает ли эта библиотека... правильно ли я все установил.. Если сделать через cout:

```
cout << ilLoadImage(L"1.jpg");
```

то просто пустая консоль...

А вообще моя цель получить массив данных картинки...

Comment: Результат функции нужно чему-то присвоить или сразу проверить с помощью if

Comment: так?
if (!ilLoadImage(L"1.jpg"))
        {
            cout << "false";
        }

Comment: Да, так.  А вот куда она загружает - неясно.

Comment: ага.. я пробовал и путь указать...

Comment: ilLoadImage(L"C:/Users/Илья/source/repos/new/new/1.jpg");

        if (ilLoadImage(L"C:/Users/Илья/source/repos/new/new/1.jpg"))
        {
            cout << "true" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "false" << endl;
        }

Comment: все ровно в консоль пишет false и все, или картинку не видит или что.. не как не проверить функция корректно работает?

Answer (score 0):

"А вообще моя цель получить массив данных картинки...". Что такое "массив данных картинки"? Имеется в виду преобразование изображения в текстовый файл с "кракозяброй"?

Если cout не перегружен для передаваемого ему типа данных, то он его и не выведет.
Нашёл библиотеку для извлечения метаданных из файлов: https://libexif.github.io/
Можно в ней поковыряться, если есть большое желание.

Comment: Здравствуйте, вообще я хочу использовать библиотеку DevIL для openGL . Что бы загружать картинки.. но как мне объяснили, сам openGL не загружает картинки, нужны стороние библиотеки. Ну как я понял эта библиотека не выдает машинный код картинки? А именно массив с количеством пикселей, цветов, и глубины? Что бы программист смог с этим разобраться?

Comment: Тут один товарищ рассматривает способ преобразования изображения в массив пикселей: [https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.781dab0b-61a7d889-d0b723ea-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/35533665/convert-image-into-array-of-pixels]